# Store and access user secrets/credentials on bot framework (Best Practice)

Tags: botframework

I’ve been doing some bots with the bot framework for the last weeks and I want to start to integrate it with other services like IOT Hub. The plan is to have to user enter its connection string (Acess key) to the IoT Hub. I will put other external services so it means keys in general.

What would the best practice for this be? Same place where user/channel data is stored? I use a table on azure storage atm.

For the moment I plan to manually add it to the azure web app settings on the portal that way they will be secured from external access but I want a more automated input/delivery for multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

> What would the best practice for this be? Same place where user/channel data is stored?

It seems that your Bot enables user to enter/provide IoT Hub connection string, if there are not too many IoT Hub connection strings need to be persisted, as you mentioned, you can store them via [Application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure) in Azure portal.

If there will be too many IoT Hub connection strings need to be persisted, you can save them in your Azure storage table, for accessing these connection strings from external applications or services, you can retrieve it from your storage table using storage SDK or [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-rest-api).

Besides, you can put the IoT Hub access key in an [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/) as a secret and have other applications retrieve the key from there.

Comment: Thx for the guidance, ive looked up the key vault I just got the feeling that it wasnt ment for external users credentials. Its possible sure. Im going to try the tables as they provide neccessary security and I can use the bot functions to store private user data. SetUserData() for example

Comment: `going to try the tables as they provide neccessary security` If you want other applications or services can access the entities stored in your tables without sharing account key for security purpose, a [SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1) is a secure way to share your storage resources.

Comment: I'm not sure what gave you the idea that Key Vault isn't meant for external credentials - that's a perfectly valid and intended use for it.